# Profile Attributes not synced

Tags: marketing-cloud

I tried to sync attributes and preferences between MC and Salesforce. No matter in which direction, if I make a change via Salesforce record or Preference Center, the fields does not get synced. Is there another setting that must be made, beside linking the attribute via email studio?

Preferences are controlled by our Parent BU and we're using PersonAccounts in Salesforce.

[image: Properties of email]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your field mappings?

Comment: Just updated the post. We're using a Parent BU and PersonAccounts, just in Case that would affect anything with Attributes.

Comment: There shouldn't be more to it according to documentation: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/setting_up_the_connector/map_attribute_fields/ - but - i haven't really worked with it as we always end up with Data Extensions and custom profile centers. Will investigate and come back.

Comment: have you tried to "display" the fields on the profile center, and then change the value in the preference center there? (just exploring a thesis)

Comment: Yes, but nothing happend. Waited for around 30min, but still not synced to SF.

Comment: I would log a support case, sitting in a MC Connect Deep Dive, and No other requirements are required for synchronization as of yet :-/

Comment: When you're using DE's wouldn't you use any attributes (nor Preferences, or Profil Atrributes) at all?

Comment: Depends on the solution and how you manage preferences. There are use cases for it, but the companies i have worked with had a setup that required custom profile center and data extensions, so there wasn't anede for attributes :)