# How does Profile Attributes sync with Salesforce?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Similar to this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181481/profile-attributes-not-synced) which doesn't have an answer, when and how does Marketing Cloud connector update 'synced' profile attributes?

I created a new attribute called Language in Marketing Cloud profile attributes that is a text field and a default value 'de'.
I have synced the field in the Salesforce tab with my Contact field.

I have two questions really:

1. When does the value get updated? I created a Contact in CRM, manually created the Subscriber in MC, then updated my Contact in CRM with new language but the Language attribute has not been updated. (the Subscriber Key is my SF 18 character ID ofc)
2. When we have a journey based on Salesforce Data (Contact record insert for example), the Contact enters the journey, on Contact insert they are created as a Subscriber in All Subscribers (if they don't already exist is my understanding), does this also copy over the synced attribute values from Salesforce CRM?

Answer (score 1):

For the second point: 
When a new contact enters the journey and receives an email, it is then inserted in 'All Subscribers'. If you are using OOB Profile Center and if the user updates the language preference, this will sync back to Salesforce. Hope this helps. :)